# Control Threads in window service using a thrid application

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, windows-services

I wrote a window service that performs some task using the threads.Now i am writing an application which controls the window service using the window service controller.There are also some threads which i want to control from this third party application.I tried to start/stop the threads using the database but it does not seems a proper solution.I think there must be some thing that would  support the controlling threads like window service controller from third application.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override OnCustomCommand in your service to allow communication from your service controller trough ExecuteCommand.

You will only be able to send numbers between 128 and 256, but if you wrap that in an enum it should be pretty workable. If you need to send more data you could still fetch that trough the database after you send a command.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.oncustomcommand.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What's worked well for me is to have a supervisor thread in my service that polls a database table for commands and in turn controls worker threads. The supervisor also writes status back to another table in the database.

The UI controller app polls the status table and writes commands to the command table. When the service responds to commands it echos the results back to the status table, giving positive feedback to the user.

I also use a third table as an activity queue that the worker threads write to and is displayed by the controller so the user can see what's happening. Limit how big the activity table can grow so that the controller doesn't have to always be running.

Guard the tables with transactions and this can run for a long time unattended.